# How to vertically center the grid container?

Tags: html, css, grid

I keep trying to center my grid container (main) vertically but won't move. Tried with align-items and still won't move.
Can anyone help me, please?

HTML:

```
<body>
<main>
  <img
    src="images/image-qr-code.png"
    width="250px"
    height="auto"
    alt="Photo of QR Code"
  />
  <h1>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h1>
  <p>
    Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to
    the next level
  </p>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 1440px;
  height: 900px;
  font-family: "Outfit", sans-serif;
  background-color: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the width on main and not on the body, that should sort it out.

Comment: I did try this but no results..

Comment: @cdr-in works on my side:
https://codepen.io/damyco/pen/eYrqZaE

Comment: I want it to look kind of like this: https://codepen.io/zzcdr/pen/vYjoKBM ; so with top and bottom margins

Comment: Ahh so you wanted to center the whole thing in the middle of the screen. Yeah you got it right! Using flex to center stuff in this way is very common.

Answer (score -1):

I actually found an answer. For those in need, I created an  for the entire grid, wrapped by . After that, I set the position on fixed, and display on flex:

```
main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```